Remove original git history for specific remote repository, but keeping it else
For my current project my project partner requires to sync my code not only with my git-server based on gitlab, but also with his git-server (unknown base). However, I don't want to expose all history details from former commits and name-changes to my project partner (as they're irrelevant). I know that I can delete the entire git-history, but I'd prefer if I could keep the entire history on my server, while only exposing all future commits to the server of my project partner (and mine, as both servers will stay in sync).
Is that possible? And if yes, how can I do that?

You can add multiple remotes, see How can I pull/push from multiple remote locations?
By default you generally have a single remote called origin, but you could have e.g. origin-gitlab and origin-git-server.
Then you could make a new branch called "squash" or whatever, then squash the entire history into a single commit using How to squash all git commits into one?
You would then push this squashed branch only to origin-git-server, but your other branches you would push to origin or origin-gitlab.
The complication will arise if you are each doing development on different remotes, as the history will diverge.

That sounds like a feasible solution. Is there any way of blocking the main branch resp. all other branches except the squashed branch to be pushed to the second remote?

Using normal Git machinery, no. But depending on the server there are add on settings in e.g GitLab, Bitbucket, etc
